# Why does a limit and continuity imply uniform continuity?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

I have a Satz that I am supposed to prove, though I don't completely understand why the Satz is true.

> The Satz states, that if a function $f:[0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
>   is continous and does have a left limit $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow
> > 1^{-}}{f(x)}$ it implies, that $f$ is uniformly continous.

It is obvious to me that $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 1^{-}}{f(x)} = x_0=\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 1^{+}}{f(x)}$ means a function is continous at $1$ but why does a limit imply anything about uniform continouity?

I also wonder why my lecturer mentions the left limit so explicitly. Sounds to me like the right limit is completely irrelevant for this statement.

Thanks in advance to the responders :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: extend $f$ to a continuous function on $[0,1]$.

There is no right limit because the function is not defined for $x > 1$.

Comment: Because we know, that every continuous function is uniformly continuous on an interval $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and if we can close the halfopen Interval it then falls under that Satz I just mentioned? Or am I thinking of it the wrong way?

Comment: You can close the half open interval......key!

Comment: Sweet. Is this also formally correct to say if $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow
> 1^{-}}{f(x)}$ exists we can say that $f:[a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ becomes to $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Asking this because I had a lot of difficulties with formalism recently.

Comment: Yes! Note that if you define $$f(1) = \lim_{x \to 1^-} f(x)$$ then $f$ is automatically a continuous function on $[0,1]$. Then use the standard result that a continuous function on a compact set is uniformly continuous and you’re good to go!